# Struts2 with struts2jquery ajax form submit display paginated table with displaytag , pagination not working

Tags: ajax, struts2, displaytag

I have a display tag with struts2 working.
I have a form submit using ajax and the result is displayed on a results div,
Now everything is fine with the display tag aided tabled displayed on the results div but,
When I try to select next on the display tag pagination tab the entire page is refreshed and the results page is displayed.

calling--Main jsp

```
<s:form method="post" action="MenuSubmit" id="form"
                                theme="simple">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><s:label>Select Category</s:label></td>
                                        <td><s:select label="Select Category" list="categoryList"
                                                listKey="id" listValue="category" name="category"
                                                tooltip="Choose Category" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr><td></td>
                                        <td><sj:submit id="btn" align="center" value="Submit"
                                                targets="res" indicator="indicator" button="true"
                                                onCompleteTopics="complete" onBeforeTopics="before" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </s:form>
                            </fieldset>

                            <img id="indicator" src="images/indicator.gif" alt="Loading..."
                                style="display: none" />
                        </div>

                        <div id=res></div>
```

Ajax called jsp

```
<display:table export="true" id="data" name="menu"
        pagesize="10" keepStatus="true" uid="one" requestURI="MenuSubmit.action">
        <display:column property="name" title="Name" sortable="true" />
        <display:column property="price" title="Price" sortable="true" />
    </display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the event default behavior and its propagation as:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```